# Spring security Class not found DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to add authentication functionality to my project and i get this issues : Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'Caused by:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/authentication/ui/DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter

---

```
  @Service
    public class MyUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.class);
        private final Map<String, String> usersAndPasswords = new HashMap<>();


        @PostConstruct
        public void initUsers() {
            // this will add a user and encode its password to md5
            // Spring StandardPasswordEncoder will add salt by default
            usersAndPasswords.put("admin", "admin");
            usersAndPasswords.put("hamou", "amroun");
        }

        @Override
        public void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

            LOGGER.debug("Authentication = {}", authentication);

            if (!usersAndPasswords.containsKey(username)) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User name not found : " + username);
            }

            String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            String encodedPassword = usersAndPasswords.get(username);
            if (!password.equals(encodedPassword)) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong password");
            }
            if (username.equals("hamou")) {
                return new User(username, "", createAuthorities("ROLE_USER"));
            } else {
                return new User(username, "", createAuthorities("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            }
        }

        public UserDetails whoMe(String username) {
            if (!usersAndPasswords.containsKey(username)) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User name not found : " + username);
            } else {

                if (username.equals("hamou")) {
                    return new User(username, "", createAuthorities("ROLE_USER"));
                } else {
                    return new User(username, "", createAuthorities("ROLE_ADMIN"));
                }
            }

        }

        private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> createAuthorities(String... roles) {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String role : roles) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
            }
            return authorities;
        }
    }
```

---

Here are my dependencies spring security and spring-boot parent

```
<!-- dependency for security -->
<dependency>
    <!-- Starter for using Spring Security -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- Make method based security testing easier -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- JSON Web Token Support -->
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- dependency for security -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

Comment: I would say, you have an dependency issue, therefor you have to post your dependency section of your POM. Use the [edit] link to add informations to your question. Don't do that in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) you mean issue in version ?

Comment: Yes, some issue with the version of Spring Security. Do you use the BOM?

Comment: Yeah and i shared it actualy i'm using 2.0.3 vesion of spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter class has been introduced in Spring Security versions to the 5.1.x line. So it's majorly coz of dependency issue, check if version is correct or simply add following dependency to your pom file-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```